# Unable to start program when running hello_world.c with Emscripten

Tags: visual-studio-2010, emscripten

I have a problem in running emscripten with vs 2010 here. It compiles all right for the hello_world.c from tests of emscripten, but when I choose "start without debugging", it prompts me that

Unable to start program 'D:\C_Drive\Desktop\emptest\msvc10\Emscripten\Debug\hello_world_c'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Getting it work :)

This is what I have done:

**Setting**

Open project properties

1. Click on the Debug dropbox (beside the run button), under it there is a configuration Manager, click on it, choose "Emscripten" as active solution platform
2. Under Configuration properties > General >Configuration Type -> Choose "Browser Application(.html)"
3. Under Configuration properties > Debugging
   Command: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
   Command Arguments: /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Emscripten\run_in_browser.bat" $(TargetPath)

**To run**

Under Debug, choose "Start Without Debugging"